# Can't find the memory leak in this code

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

I've been looking for over 2 hours and it turns out my memory leak is coming from this section, only I am unable to determine what is causing the leak. BTW, I am using Allegro5, but made some wrappers.

```
void WidgetLabel::updateBitmap( Display* display )
{

    Size textSize = getTextSize( _font, _text.c_str() );

    _bitmap = createBitmap( textSize.getWidth(), textSize.getHeight(), display );

    startDrawingToBitmap( _bitmap );
        drawText( _font, _color, Point(0,0), _text.c_str() );
    stopDrawingToBitmap( _bitmap, display );

}
```

Edit: I thought I might need to delete the _bitmap to free the space before creating a new one, but the application keeps crashing when doing so. I am guessing it is because of how Allegro manages memory. With Allegro, you must do:

```
al_destroy_bitmap( ALLEGRO_BITMAP* bitmap );
```

Comment: Are you 100% sure that's the leak? Try commenting it out temporarily and see if it really is the leak.

Comment: Your intuition about `_bitmap` leaking seems right to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `createbitmap` allocates memory, are you overwriting `_bitmap` always, when you call `updateBitmap()` ? (Is there any statement you are missing to manage `_bitmap` ?)

It might crash, if `_bitmap` is not initialized and you are trying to `free` it. You can initialize `_bitmap` in constructor as `0` and then check for NULL before freeing it. i.e.

```
if(_bitmap != 0)
  delete or free (_bitmap);
```

Comment: I tried setting _bitmap to 0 before deleting, and then creating a new bitmap on it, and not it did not crash, but the memory leak is still present

Comment: Don't set _bitmap to `0` before delete. just check my edited answer above.

Comment: There's no need to check for NULL before deleting or freeing it.

Comment: @user422382, you need to set _bitmap to 0 in the WidgetLabel constructor, not in the updateBitmap() method. Don't set it to 0 before deleting either, or al_destroy_bitmap() won't know what to destroy.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It solved it. After verifying if it was null, I created a bitmap. If it was not NULL, I delete the bitmap, and then a create a new one using the same pointer. No more memory leak!

Answer (score 1):

Well you need to delete things when you create them on the heap. It sounds like you need to delete _bitmap, but only if you've used it before; it would crash if you hadn't set it to something before you tried to delete it.

Answer (score 1):

If I may be completely honest, `createBitmap()` is not the counterpart of `al_destroy_bitmap()`.

`al_create_bitmap()` is.

Your createBitmap() may have come from somewhere else. Check it's signature.

Comment: Updated answer. What's the signature of createBitmap? You are probably calling the wrong function to deallocate the bitmap.

Answer (score 0):

A few thoughts:

1. How do you know that you have a memory leak? What is your indication of this? Sometimes the task manager or `top` are inaccurate, because while the memory has been freed, it may not have been re-allocated by the OS yet.
2. If you are calling this function repeatedly, it may be that _bitmap is being allocated (using createBitmap) but its memory is not being free()'d. Is there also a "DestroyBitmap" or "FreeBitmap" function?

Comment: 1) I know its a memory leak because I commented out this function and looked at the ram. It was stable, then I looped this function 10000 times, and I got 170MB of ram occupied and did not decrease after that. 2) There is only a delete function provided by allegro

Answer (score 0):

If _bitmap already contains another image when you createBitmap, you will lose that pointer and leak memory. Additionally, as you mentioned, you need to destroy the bitmap as well.

It may be worth your time to find out why it's crashing if you do free the bitmap, are you reusing the pointer to the freed bitmap again unintentionally?

Comment: Yeah, I was planning on using this same pointer for the new bitmap I create.